# Unable to connect to SPOService using Pswh on Mac

Tags: macos, powershell, sharepoint

first I want to state that I am a novice when it comes to code/programming. Also, I have a Mac (that runs Catalina, if that matters).

This is my first time posting to this forum, so please forgive any missteps in protocol...

Here's some background info to my question:
I have Microsoft 365 for Business and I use Teams. I'm a small business and I'm the owner and administrator. I need to be able to share externally with anyone. I have changed the settings in SharePoint admin and OneDrive admin to be able to share externally. Look here to see an example of what I have done, and the problem: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/onedrive-for-business/share-with-anyone-with-the-link-setting-is-grey-out-why/m-p/810390

Even after allowing for external sharing, the sharing options are still greyed-out. But this is not my question. I know how to fix it; as it says in the above link, I need to enable sharing in Powershell via `set-sposite "siteurl" -sharingcapability ExternalUserAndGuestSharing`

After some research, I found that there is a Microsoft Pwsh for Mac. I downloaded Homebrew, Microsoft PowerShell and Azure. (I also have Node.js, if that matters.) Here is a screenshot of my terminal (I hid any identifying information...):
[terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh7cw.png)

As you can see, I get this error: `Connect-SPOService -Url https://<organization name here>admin.sharepoint.com Connect-SPOService: The term 'Connect-SPOService' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

I contacted Microsoft and had a technician with me on the phone trying to troubleshoot their way into my SPOService on my Mac using Homebrew in order to fix the greyed-out "share with anyone" option. We were unsuccessful. At the moment, I do have access to a Windows computer, and I was able to enter my SPOService on that Windows computer and resolve the problem. However, for each new SharePoint site I create and want to share externally, I will need to repeat this process (at least, this is what the technician told me). I will not always have access to a Windows computer, therefore I need to be able to enter my SPOService on my Macbook.

Are there any workarounds? Is there an SPOService powershell for Mac? If I have the pswh for Microsoft, why won't it let me into sharepoint?

Thank you in advance for any assistance

Answer (score 2):

First, I can still not rename the domain, but I can help you with a general SharePoint update. It does not work either in Azure or on Mac OX X.

If you like to check, repeat the following steps on your computer setup, assuming you don't use a Windows Computer.

## Check the availability of SharePoint

```
Get-Module -Name Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -ListAvailable | Select Name,Version
```

## Install the module if missing

### On a mac with the name of your user directory

```
Import-Module /Users/username/.local/share/powershell/Modules Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -Verbose
```

### On Azure Powershell

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -Verbose
```

You get a PowerShell via a one-month Test-Subscription.

## Prepare your Admin URL

```
$AdminCenterURL="https://name_you_used_during_first_setup-admin.sharepoint.com"
```

Make sure you add "-admin" at the end of your domain name. You received this when you signed up. It is not the domain name you can use for your subscription later; it's, unfortunately, how Microsoft decided to implement it. Therefore, changing from Mac or Azure is not possible.

## Connect to your side

```
Connect-SPOService -Url $AdminCenterURL -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

And now it will fail with

```
Connect-SPOService: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Win32.Registry' threw an exception.
```

Unfortunately, after exchanging many emails with Microsoft, I could not resolve this with the Support desk. However, the error seems to be known.

I wrote this note to allow others to save valuable time so that somebody would not waste his time if they tried to resolve it as I tried.

If like me, you are stuck with renaming the initial SharePoint subdomain, you currently have the following options.

- Buy a Windows PC with a License or install a VM with a MS Windows trial license
- Buy an Enterprise License, and use the Beta functionality.
- Delete your subscription, but then you might lose the active licenses and the work you have put in already. But you can re-register, and this time put the name into the subscription, which you like to see as a subdomain of SharePoint. But you lose all work put in, in the first place.

Comment: I solved it now by using the free azure subscription for one month and the included Windows VM. Here I installed the above and closed the issue for us. Not ideal, but a way out of a deadlock if you prefer Linux or mac environments.